# Insert into table that uses Clustered Columnstore index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, clustered-index

I want to insert into a table that uses clustered columnstore index.
My logic is the following. First i am checking if the table has clustered columnstore index and then drop the index, insert the new data and finally create again the clustered columnstore index.

Here is my sample code.

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
if exists (select i.name as indexname, 
       t.name as tablename
from   sys.indexes i
  join sys.tables t on i.object_id = t.object_id
where  i.type in (5, 6) and t.name = 'cci_table')
begin
        set @sql = '
                    DROP CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX cci ON dbo.cci_table'
        print @sql

        /** insert data to cci_table **/

        set @sql = '
                    CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX cci ON dbo.cci_table'  
        print @sql
end
else
begin
        set @sql = '
                    CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX cci ON dbo.cci_table'  
        print @sql
end
```

Is it a good approach do it like this?
Is there a different way to insert data in clustered columnstored index table, or do i have to drop current index and then create index again?

Comment: Why would you do this? Only in SQL Server 2012 did a (non-clustered) columnstore index render a table read-only, but SQL Server 2012 did not support CCIs (if I'm not mistaken). In other words, why not simply do the update and let the engine take care of it?

Comment: @Jeroen Monsert then it makes no sense to drop and then create the CCI. In that case of update how the query would be like? Just inserting data into the dbo.cci_table?

Comment: Well, yes. Although inserts and updates in a columnstore are much less efficient than a rowstore, the engine can handle them using what's known as a delta store. If you can batch rows, you should -- see the [data loading guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-data-loading-guidance) -- but individual rows will work too. The full breakdown is -- 2012 had readonly non-clustered columnstores, 2014 had updatable clustered columnstores (but readonly non-clustered columnstores), 2016 makes non-clustered columnstores updatable as well.

Comment: Regardless of version 2012-2016, you can also use partition switching which would most likely be a lot better in terms of performance as well. That does require a lot more work up front though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not needed to drop and then create columnstore index as tables that use columnstore index are updatable.
That means that i can insert new data to existing columnstore table if the index exists with no problem.

```
 declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
    if exists (select i.name as indexname, 
           t.name as tablename
    from   sys.indexes i
      join sys.tables t on i.object_id = t.object_id
    where  i.type in (5, 6) and t.name = 'cci_table')
    begin

            /** insert data to cci_table **/

    end
    else
    begin
            set @sql = '
                        CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX cci ON dbo.cci_table'  
            print @sql

            /** insert data to cci_table **/

    end
```